Нужна ли запятая между союзами И и КАК в данном предложении?

Пропади ты совсем! - желали третьи, и(?) как ни отмахивали руками от своего берега путников, они были под самым городским взвозом.


В качестве варианта:
—  Пропади ты совсем! — желали третьи; но как ни отмахивали руками от своего берега путников, они были под самым городским взвозом.
Пояснение
Формально уступительное придаточное надо бы обособить по обычным правилам о возможности перетановки придаточного, но такая графика выглядит не вполне корректно. Соединительный союз И лучше заменить противительным союзом  НО с уступительным оттенком значения.

Согласен. Здесь противительный союз но относится к последующей части?

Спасибо, Серж! А как вы относитесь к такой идее. Если я ставлю точку с запятой. то это почти точка. И тогда союз НО становится  как бы присоединительным, а такие союзы относятся ко всему СПП. Поэтому нет запятой.

Шарон, согласен. Вчера я думал над этим вопросом. Непонятно было, к какой части относится союз и. Если убрать придаточное, тогда получилось бы: — Пропади ты совсем! — желали третьи, и они были были... Но смысл теряется. Поэтому ваше решение оправдано.
